# Edit Json file inside a foreach

Tags: php, json, laravel

A pleasure, I have a query to do how to edit a data from my database that is json as it is in the image
[image]

This would be my json data that I want to edit [{"id":90641,"component_id":"8","sub_component":"15","servicios":"1085","quantity":1,"cost ":"18644.27"},{"id":85879,"component_id":"8","sub_component":"15","servicios":"1086","quantity":1,"cost ":"524.72"}]

In my controller, it accesses the data with a double foreach but I don't know how to edit the json file with the data that I pass through the route

```
public function UpdateCantidadEdit($id,$quantity){
$tasks= Tasks::where('id',$tid)->get();
foreach($tasks as $task) {
    foreach($task->componente_id as $item) {
        if ($item['servicios'] == $id) { 
            $item['quantity'] = $quantity; 
            break;
        }
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: use 'json_decode($task->componente_id) as $item'

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit string as a PHP array. Firstly, you need to **decode your JSON string** by using **json_decode** php function. Please, specify a second argument as true to decode JSON as associative array
Try this one:

```
public function UpdateCantidadEdit($id,$quantity){
    $tasks= Tasks::where('id',$tid)->get();

    foreach($tasks as $task) {
        foreach(json_decode($task->componente_id, true) as $item) {
            if ($item['servicios'] == $id) { 
                $item['quantity'] = $quantity; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```